is it ok to source electrical wire from the scrap metal yard?
The rare question that requires no exposition.  Except to say that it's still on a spool (not just a loose pile of wire), and that it's to be used for house wiring.  Mostly NM-B (aka. Romex).

If the NM-B has been outdoors, forget it.  Getting wet rots the insulation.  We know because we see it trip GFCIs.

Just a side-note: depending where you live, scrapyard electrical conductors are mostly stolen. I'm not trying to moralize or anything, but it sometimes can save you some embarrassment to be aware of this.

I suppose it could be, but I think scrapyards are pretty careful about that these days.   Anyhow, it'll probably be a one-off for me.

That should be OK. Unlike a device with actual electronic components (receptacle, breaker, etc.) that could have hidden and hard to detect damage, cable is a pretty simple thing.
About the only real concern is water damage. NM cable in particular is not for use in wet areas. If it got wet - e.g., the spool was in a flooded warehouse - it might look OK but be damaged.

And if it wasn't in a flood, expect to remove and scrap 5-10 feet on each end if it ever sat out in the rain.

It probably also matters how long it was there being rain/snow on.  A few months during a dry season will be much better than a few years.  Is NM-B insulation good in the sun?

@Ecnerwal: Are there any kinds of water damage that could cause trouble down the road without being obvious?

@crip659 They actually have their wire inside a shipping container.   I suppose it could've been exposed to the elements at some point though.  I'll strip off some of the sheath and have a look (made that comment before, but it disappeared, I guess because I linked to a specific tool that does a great job of stripping Romex sheath cleanly).

@RustyShackleford   Inside a container is good.   With the price of copper and/or having to protect it from being stolen, it does seem a bit odd, unless a small spool.

Looks like there's 100-200ft on it.  When I googled this question (my OP) all I got was advice to electricians on selling wire for scrap.
